# Ok, I really don't get on with JSON stuff?

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I've managed to get a JSON output from my database for use with jQuery UI AutoComplete, and that's working fine.

The trouble with it is, it seems the AutoComoplete plugin does all the parsing of JSON data for me, so I'm still to work out how that's actually done.

I have a URL, http://test.hartnollguitars.co.uk/jsonOut/products.aspx?term=761294042656&barcode=yes (as an example) which gives me a single record from the same JSON output as I use for Autocomplete, I am trying to use this single record output for a single case.

So I've been Googling and messing around with jQuery getJSON, but I seem unable to get the info.

```
$.getJSON("jsonOut/products.aspx?barcode=yes", function () { alert(data.label);  });
```

Is kind of where I'm at now, I know this is wrong and I have tried various other permutations of this code following examples from the jQuery site, but I just can't get the output I need.

It's obviously because I've got no idea what I am doing, but can someone just explain how you:

1. Get data from a single record like this
2. Get data from a series of data and loop through to display the output (for example from an FQL output from the Facebook Graph for a simple object such as events)

All help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you certain the data is being transferred? Firebug or Chrome's or IE's developer tools can help you be sure.

Comment: Do you provide the JSON data? If so, why do you add brackets? Just use `{"label":"Boss TR-2 Tremolo Pedal","price":79,"id":1287}`. Works the same way and will probably solve your first issue. With brackets you start an array but why to do this if you only have one entry?

Comment: Got it... I thought it was something to do with the square brackets, but they are relevant, it's used for multiple result queries too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remeber to use an absolute url, not a relative. The code you have pasted will append the url to the current directory, so it will only work if it is coming from `/`.
The JSON being returned is an array, so you have to dereference an element:

```
$.getJSON("/jsonOut/products.aspx?barcode=yes", function (data) { alert(data[0].label);  });
```

or the more useful thing to do would be:

```
$.getJSON("/jsonOut/products.aspx?barcode=yes", function (data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      alert(data[i].label);
   }
});
```

Comment: I had to accept this answer as it gives me the data looping as well. No offence to all the other excellent answers!! :D

Answer (score 4):

`data` does not come from nowhere, its a parameter to your success function

```
$.getJSON(
     "jsonOut/products.aspx?barcode=yes", 
     function (data) { 
         alert(data.label);  
});
```

And you output an array

```
[
   {
        "label": "Boss TR-2 Tremolo Pedal",
        "price": 79,
        "id": 1287
    }
]
```

Thats what the '[]' braches stand for, so your data can be accessed in another way

```
data[0].label
```

Please consider developing in Firefox and using FireBug, then you could write

```
console.log(data);
```

instead of alert(), wich will give you much greater insight into your objects.

Comment: Oh, excellent. I've never used console.log, but I will try it. I do use Firefox/Firebug and Chrome Developer tools, I find both have their pros and cons. Generally Firebug wins, but there's a couple of nice features to the developer tools in Chrome.

Comment: Great, console.log will also work in chrome - but personally I prefere Firebug (allway).

Answer (score 4):

I looked at your JSON Output:
`[{"label":"Boss TR-2 Tremolo Pedal","price":79,"id":1287}]`

The Problem is, that your Code outputs a List of Objects.
Try `data[0].label` instead.

Comment: That's it thanks. I thought it was something to do with the square brackets, but they are relevant, it's used for multiple result queries too.

Comment: No Prob. Just a little advice for you: if you use Firebug, you could use the Firebug Console to simply paste your JSON into Firebug.
Example: `data = {"a":"b"}` if you type data["a"] then, it will output `b`;)